# How to verify the graphs displayed in web page using protractor?

Tags: typescript, protractor, e2e-testing

I am working on UI verification of an webpage, in that I need to verify Graphs and tool tip(on hovering).How do I perform using Protractor (typescript) ?

Need to verify the below graph and the tool tips on hovering over it using protractor.

[Analysis Graph to be verified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvVHw.png)

Comment: Share your implementation and error or html to give more input on the issue.

Comment: Hi @Madhan I have not tried yet since I am new to Protractor and type script I am trying to get some ideas to handle it. I have attached the screenshot of the graph(Which I need to verify) in the description.

Comment: To answer your question you can validate the tooltip using protractor. I am not sure about the graph